# How do I find ftp information of page to query via php?

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to work on a personal script to auto-update an addon for a game. I want to automate the update process which is:

1. Visit link: https://www.deltaconnected.com/arcdps/x64/
2. Download d3d9.dll file
3. Replace local file.

How would I go about requesting the info of the files on the above page to compare to my local file's md5 and replace if different, in PHP.

Since, to me, this looks like an ftp directory I have tried using *ftp_connect()* but without the ftp.xxxx.xxx info I am not able to do what I want.

Comment: That is not FTP, it is an Apache-generated page listing the contents of a folder without an `index.html` (or other DirectoryIndex) file. So you will not be able to use the `ftp_*` functions on that URL, unless that website specifically provide an FTP URL for that purpose.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Thank you for the answer. I am now trying to find a way to query this page for the information/files and if it meets my criteria then download the file using my script. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Just use something like cURL to download the md5sum-file and validate it. If it doesn't match your current, just download the dll-file. This should be easy since you have the direct links to the files. Make some attempts and come back if you run into some _specific_ issue. Currently, it's a bit too broad.

Comment: As @MagnusEriksson suggested I managed to complete what I wanted.

I used the direct link of the file I wanted from the above page and using cURL I downloading after comparing the MD5 of my local file and the MD5 of the file URL.